# Game Window (no longer) Stays Open

Tags: c++, visual-studio, window

I'm working on a simple game to test some stuff and I'm using something called the DX Library, which is basically a library that simplifies Direct X. Anyway, I'm using Visual Studio 2013, I debugged and ran and it worked fine. I literally didn't change the code at all, came back to it a few minutes later, after doing some stuff in an other program I'm writing at the same time in a different project in Visual Studio, I run it again and this time the window opens, it's completely black, it sits there for a few seconds, then closes. I made sure that it properly closed the last time I ran it, and even shut down and restarted visual studio, and it still does the same thing. I don't know if it's the code (although again, I hadn't touched it since the last time it ran) or if it's a visual studio thing. Since I'm using the Dx Library it may be hard to follow the code but I'll put it all below.

main.cpp

```
#include "main.h"

//Global variables

int g_lasttime = 0;  //time of last calculation.
float g_frametime = 0; //amount of time for one loop.
int g_timerstart; //variable used by timer.

GameState g_gamestate = GAME_TITLE;

int g_gametitleimg;         //title image
int g_heroimg;              //character image
float g_hx, g_hy;       //coordinates.

//Button
BOOL g_akey_prev; //previous state of A button

//font
int g_middlefont;  //medium sized font.
int g_largefont;   //large sized font.

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE h1, HINSTANCE hp, LPSTR lpC, int nC)
{
    //Setting Window Mode
    ChangeWindowMode(TRUE);

    //Set Window Size.
    SetGraphMode(800, 600, 32);

    //Initiating DxLib
    if (DxLib_Init() == -1)return -1;

    //Loading image
    if (LoadGameImage() == FALSE) return -1;
    g_gametitleimg = LoadGraph("media\\Comp Title.png");
    g_heroimg = LoadGraph("media\\g7.png");
    g_middlefont = CreateFontToHandle("メリオ", 42, -1, DX_FONTTYPE_ANTIALIASING);

    SetDrawScreen(DX_SCREEN_BACK);
    g_lasttime = GetNowCount() & INT_MAX; //registers current time.

    while (ProcessMessage() == 0 && CheckHitKey(KEY_INPUT_ESCAPE) == 0)
    {
        //Calculating time for 1 loop.
        int curtime = GetNowCount();
        g_frametime = (float)(curtime - g_lasttime) / 1000.0f;
        g_lasttime = curtime;

        ClearDrawScreen();

        //Changing screen drawing functions
        switch (g_gamestate)
        {
        case GAME_TITLE:
            DrawGameTitle();
            break;
        //case GAME_CUT_SCENE:
            //DrawCutScene();
            //break;
        case GAME_MAIN:
            DrawGameMain();
            break;
        case GAME_CLEAR:
            DrawGameClear();
            break;
        case GAME_OVER:
            DrawGameOver();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }


        ScreenFlip();
    }

    WaitKey();

    //Stopping DxLib
    DxLib_End();

    return 0;
}

//Draw Title
void DrawGameTitle()
{
    DrawBox(0, 0, 800, 600, GetColor(225, 225, 225), TRUE);
    DrawGraph(0, 0, g_gametitleimg, TRUE);
    int ghandle = LoadGraph("media\\titlegirl.png");
    DrawGraph(300, 200, ghandle, TRUE);


    //Displaying text
    DrawStringToHandle(50, 300, "Press Z To Start", GetColor(255,0,255),g_middlefont);
    DrawStringToHandle(50, 360, "Use Arrow Keys To Move", GetColor(0, 0, 0), g_middlefont);

    //Check if key is pressed
    int key = GetJoypadInputState(DX_INPUT_KEY_PAD1);
    if (IsAKeyTrigger(key) == TRUE)g_gamestate = GAME_MAIN;
}
//Main Game
void DrawGameMain()
{
    GameMain();
}

//Draw Clear screen
void DrawGameClear()
{

}
//Draw Game Over screen
void DrawGameOver()
{
    //DrawStringToHandle(100, 600, "Wait to return to Main Menu", GetColor(255, 150, 255), g_middlefont);
    int ghandle = LoadGraph("media\\gameover.png");
    DrawGraph(800, 600, ghandle, TRUE);
    //returns to main menu after 5 seconds.
    if (g_lasttime - g_timerstart > 5000)g_gamestate = GAME_TITLE;

}

//Key Trigger Proccess
BOOL IsAKeyTrigger(int key)
{
    if (key & PAD_INPUT_A)
    {
        if (g_akey_prev == FALSE)
        {
            g_akey_prev = TRUE;
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        g_akey_prev = FALSE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

main.h

```
#ifndef _MAIN_H_
#define _MAIN_H_

#include <DxLib.h>
#include "gamemain.h"
#include "loading.h"

//Global variables

extern int g_lasttime;  //time of last calculation.
extern float g_frametime; //amount of time for one loop.
extern int g_timerstart; //variable used by timer.

enum GameState{
    GAME_TITLE, GAME_MAIN,
    //GAME_CUT_SCENE,
    GAME_CLEAR, GAME_OVER
};

extern GameState g_gamestate;
extern int g_gametitleimg;          //title image
extern int g_heroimg;               //character image
extern float g_hx, g_hy;        //coordinates.

//Button
extern BOOL g_akey_prev; //previous state of A button

//font
extern int g_middlefont;  //medium sized font.
extern int g_largefont;   //large sized font.

//Declaring function prototypes
extern void DrawGameTitle();
extern void DrawGameMain();
//extern void DrawCutScene();
extern void DrawGameClear();
extern void DrawGameOver();
extern BOOL IsAKeyTrigger(int key);


#endif
```

gamemain.h

```
#ifndef _GAMEMAIN_H_
#define _GAMEMAIN_H_

#include <DxLib.h>
#include "main.h"

#define IMG_CHIP_SIZE   50
#define MAP_WIDTH       16
#define MAP_HEIGHT      12

void GameMain();
void DrawMap();

#endif
```

gamemain.cpp

```
void GameMain()
{
    DrawMap();
    //Character Movement
    int key = GetJoypadInputState(DX_INPUT_KEY_PAD1);
    float mv = 80.0f*g_frametime; //calc for movement.
    if (key&PAD_INPUT_UP)       g_hy -= mv;
    if (key&PAD_INPUT_DOWN)     g_hy += mv;
    if (key&PAD_INPUT_LEFT)     g_hx -= mv;
    if (key&PAD_INPUT_RIGHT)    g_hx += mv;
    DrawGraph(g_hx, g_hy, g_heroimg, TRUE);
    //Check if Z is pressed
    if (IsAKeyTrigger(key) == TRUE)
    {
        g_gamestate = GAME_OVER;
        g_timerstart = g_lasttime; //set timer
    }
}

void DrawMap()
{
    for (int y = 0; y < MAP_HEIGHT; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < MAP_WIDTH; x++)
        {
            DrawGraph(x*IMG_CHIP_SIZE, y*IMG_CHIP_SIZE, g_imghandles.field, FALSE);
        }
    }
}
```

loading.h

```
#ifndef _LOADING_H_
#define _LOADING_H_

#include <DxLib.h>

struct ImageHandles
{
    int field; //background
};
extern ImageHandles g_imghandles;

BOOL LoadGameImage();

#endif
```

loading.cpp

```
#include "loading.h"

ImageHandles g_imghandles;

BOOL LoadGameImage()
{
    g_imghandles.field = LoadGraph("media\\bgbrick.png");
    if (g_imghandles.field == -1) return FALSE;

    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: What did you try so far to debug it?

Comment: I guess `main` returns -1? It could be that some other project changes your working paths inside VS, so it can't rind resource files anymore.

Comment: Thanks I figured it out and got it working again. There were some paths that I didn't realize had changed, so the images weren't loading.